# VW Polo 1.4 TDI 2007 - not starting

Tags: engine, starting, starter, cold-start, low-oil

I've searched all over the internet, but didn't find anything exact.

**Context:**

I drive ~11km twice a working day on average.
I was dumb and didn't check oil regularly. One day driving back home a yellow "Low oil" light comes up, yes I need to fill it up. 2 km from home, with the light on I drive home, park. Having limp mode, I thought maybe just a sensor thing, so when I parked and turned the car off, I tried restarting the car, but it screamed low oil and refused. Alright, left it for the night and in the morning I filled it with 5w30 to the exact midpoint. It started, but hesitantly, like in winter.

**The problem:**

When I tried turning it on, the starter cranked a few times and that's it. The second time it cranked once or twice and from that point turning on the ignition engages only the fuel pump and a click around the starter.

**Things already tried:**

- Connected alligator clips to the battery from another running car, no difference, battery
  works good, wipers, etc. work normally.
- Starting from second, third, etc. gear while pulled, no effect. Engine failure?
- Changed key's battery.
- Hit the starter with a metal rod a few times, no effect. Solenoid ok?

I'm not a cars guy, so this is extra hard and confusing.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!